# Ploting online data on google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-maps

I'm looking for developing an application which can plot clients activity on the map . The clients are production floors , and they are distributed all over the world . I want to plot points on the map and refresh them on runtime so it can reflect clients production status .
Would you please recommend and demo or looks doing that on google maps or any other solution .

Thanks in advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has lots of examples on their site: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

You'll need at least one web service that the various locations will be able to submit their productivity status, then store that data.

Then, you could

1) generate the page dynamically, pulling those data points into some array, and cycle through the array, adding markers (and, at the point each marker is added, you'll probably elect to use a custom icon depending on what their productivity level is, so that you have a visual indicator)

OR

2) make another web service that can be queried, and give that response. This way, you could have the page periodically clear it's markers, request new data, and plot them, so that you'd have a self updating dashboard

Here is a sample page that does something similar (without custom marker icons):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>SEPTA Route Map</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<style>
#wrap {width:960px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;position:relative;}
#map_canvas {width:100%;height:700px;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="wrap">
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
</div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),myOptions);
var markers=new Array();
var first=0;
update();

function update(){
    var bounds2 = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var xmlhttp;
    xmlhttp=((window.XMLHttpRequest)?new XMLHttpRequest():new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"));
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            res=JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
            //clear existing markers
            for (x=0;x<markers.length;x++) {
                markers[x].setMap(null);
            }
            markers=new Array();
            //draw new markers
            for(i=0;i<res['bus'].length;i++){
                var a=new Object();
                a.lat=res.bus[i]['lat'];
                a.lng=res.bus[i]['lng'];
                var point=new google.maps.LatLng(a.lat,a.lng);
                bounds2.extend(point);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: point,map: map});
                markers.push(marker);
            }
            if(first==0){
                map.fitBounds(bounds2);
                first++;
            }
            setTimeout(update,2000);

        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","so_septa_data.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}   

</script>
</html>
```

You'll see that it's calling to so_septa_data.php every 2 seconds (the `setTimeout` line)
and that file is just:

```
<?php
$route=(isset($_REQUEST['route']))?$_REQUEST['route']:23;
echo file_get_contents("http://www3.septa.org/transitview/bus_route_data/".$route);
?>
```

Yours will likely consist of just connecting to your database, gathering the results, formatting them into JSON or XML, and echoing the results.